# Программирование.

Tags: html, css, оптимизация-сайтов

Какие языки программирования нужно изучать для создания сайтов?

Comment: слишком общий вопрос

Comment: Да почти любые.

Comment: Если вы еще ничего не учили, начните с верстки,  HTML5 / CSS3. Ну а после HTML/CSS как вариант JavaScript, неполохо бы было знать, далее хоть базовый PHP, далее базы данных, с CMS поиграйтесь. Коротоко говоря, времени надо много

Comment: минусовать не надо ! чувак то впервые здесь

Comment: @НикитаФаст и что из этого? Человек даже не вбивал запрос на схожий вопрос, тут таких сотни дублей и закрытых. Справку не читал..., ну и т.д.

Comment: @VladSpirin я не о про поиск а  о том что мы все должны быть снисходительны .... наличие большой кармы не говорит о том что можно обкакать карму другим ну и в конце  концов "Мы же дружелюбное сообщество"

Comment: @НикитаФаст а какой карме вы говорите? Вот я вам приведу пример, чтоб вы поняли мою предыдущую мысль. Вы приходите "условно" в налоговую и вам надо заполнить декларацию. Вы ее как будете заполнять??? Интуитивно??? (это печальный вариант с последствиями), и если же вы адекватный человек, вы глянете в бланк инструкцию , на стенде. Так и тут... А про минусы...., как раз писал на днях: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8168/%d0%9c%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%83%d1%82-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b3%d0%bb%d1%83%d0%bf%d1%8b%d0%bc%d0%b8/8171#8171

Comment: @VladSpirin жаль ... потому и stackoverflow боятся как огня .. а могло быть всё по другому ... я не защищаю и понимаю что SO это база знаний

Comment: @НикитаФаст со временем поймете, гляньте ссылку. Пока тут не почистили все и не закрыли вопрос. А то что боятся..., это хорошо. Вы хотите быть профи, или аматором?(вопрос риторический) Человек, задал вопрос, я ему дал достойный ответ в комментарии, а воспользуется ли автор, это уже его дело

Comment: @VladSpirin  классно .. плюс  в репу ... мне понравилось ..